# Android Studio cannot resolve method after Importing a Project

Tags: android-studio

I am new in Android Studio environment. My IDE Version is Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1. I have been unable to fix this issue for quite some time. I was recently assigned to an already developed Android Studio Project. So, I downloaded it from the git. But after opening it, Android Studio is showing me loads of errors of same type.
The IDE cannot resolve other class's functions or variables which are used with get and set function.
What is even more confusing to me, when I run the 'app' it builds and runs successfully.

Thanks in advance.

I have Invalidated Caches, Restarted IDE, discarded the whole project and again downloaded from git. But these errors are not going away.

Comment: Is it possibe for you to add a picture? might be something with your settings or gradle configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this problem.
Do not worry. The problem is actually the Lombok Plugin. Android Studio's latest versions do not support it natively.
Here is what you need to do:

1. Go to this URL:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/versions
2. Check out the latest version and download.
3. Unzip it in your Downloaded Directory.
4. Then copy the containing "lombok-plugin" folder and paste it to
   Android Studio/plugins directory.
5. Invalidate Cache (Optional)
6. Restart IDE

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always thought the solution would be very simple. I was probably looking in the other direction.